# REST URL for transforming one resource into another resource

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, restful-url

I am struggling to come with proper REST URL for converting one resource into another. The API method does not do any CRUD operations but instead transform/convert one resource into another type of resource.

I have 2 resources `Workunit` and `Document`. I have 3 operations on these two resources

1> trasform `Workunit` into `Document`
2> sync `Workunit` into `Document`  (different logic than transform)
3> transform `Document` into `Workunit`

and i have the following urls

```
[POST]  api/v1/workunits/transform
[POST]  api/v1/workunits/sync
[POST]  api/v1/documents/transform
```

problem here is action is a part of REST URL

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> problem here is action is a part of REST URL

That's not a problem - clients don't depend on the URL for semantics, so you can use any spelling you like; `api/v1/4dc233fa-c77c-49d7-b7d6-296ffeb89612` is perfectly satisfactory.

It's analogous to having a verb as a variable name -- it may not be in keeping with your local coding standards, but the compiler doesn't care.  So too is it with your URL and the general purpose components that use it.

Choosing a good identifier is like choosing a good name; it requires having a clear understanding of what the thing is.  In the case of URI/URL, the thing being identified is a resource, which is to say something that is described by a document.  GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and so on are all requests that we do something interesting with the underlying document.

So the usual pattern might be to POST a `transform` message to the workunit resource, or to POST a `transform` message to the Document resource, or to POST a sync message to the workunit resource.

Hmm, that last one sounds backwards; if the workunit is unchanged, and the Document is changed by the sync, then you would probably send a sync message to the Document resource.

So if I have /api/v1/documents/1, and I need to sync it, then I would normally use `POST /api/v1/documents/1`, with the sync semantics described in the message body (on the web, that would usually be an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` representation of the sync message).

But it could just as easily be a message that says "Sync documents/1 with workitem/2" that I `POST` to the todo list for the synchronizer.

We are just [putting documents politely into the server's in-tray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s), so that it can do useful work.  The in-tray can have whatever label you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine with given situation.

Nevertheless, if I am getting you right it may be a good idea to create two different controllers.

It's up to you but think of changing structure a little bit:

Separate the logic of `Transformation` and `Sync` into two different controllers, so you can avoid URL issue.

- `TransformationController`

  ```
  [Route("api/v1/transformation-controller/")]
  TransformationController : ControllerBase
  {
       [HttpPost("workunits")]
       public Task<Response> TransformWorkunits()
       {
            //logic
       }

       [HttpPost("documents")]
       public Task<Response> TransformDocuments()
       {
            //logic
       }
  }
  ```
- `SynchronizationController`

  ```
  [Route("api/v1/synchronization-controller/")]
  TransformationController : ControllerBase
  {
       [HttpPost("workunits")]
       public Task<Response> SyncWorkunits()
       {
            //logic
       }
  }
  ```

So the URLs will be:

- `[POST]  api/v1/transformation-controller/workunits`
- `[POST]  api/v1/synchronization-controller/workunits`
- `[POST]  api/v1/transformation-controller/documents`

So this is a way to avoid verbs and fit REST rules.

If there will be more objects to transform/sync from and into, then you'll have to **improve** this approach.